# how to print the data accepted from user in the list in python?

Tags: python-3.7

[image]

I want to print the constructed list but it shows index out of range error.  How do I do it?

```
students = []
marks = []
num = int(input("How many students?:  "))
for i in range(1,num):
     name = input("input name of student ")
     students.append(name)
     mark = input("input mark of the student")
     marks.append(mark)
     i+=1
for i in range(1,num):
     print(students[i] + ": "+marks[i])
```

Comment: Python arrays are `0`-based. Thus, if you have `num` students, `students[0]` till `students[num - 1]` are valid; `students[num]` is out of bounds. (E.g. for 3 students, you have `students[0]`, `students[1]` and `students[2]`, but not `students[3]`). Use `range(num)` instead of `range(1, num)`.

Comment: Can you please provide more information then "it show index out of range"?

Comment: `range(1, 3)` in the first loop will let you enter 2 students. Then `range(3)` in the second loop will want to print 3 students. Make it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I will break this problem step by step

```
students = []
marks = []
num = int(input("How many students?:  "))
for i in range(1,num):
     name = input("input name of student ")
     students.append(name)
     mark = input("input mark of the student")
     marks.append(mark)
```

Input section

```
How many students?:  2
input name of student stark
input mark of the student22
```

In this code :

```
students list =['stark']
Marks list=['22']
```

But in your another for loop

```
for i in range(1,num):
    print(students[i] + ": "+marks[i])
```

this will not work because python index starts with 0 and your for loop starting with 1 and you can print those values at `students[0]` only not `students[1]` as per according to your loop

```
for i in range(num-1):  #because num value is 2 and provided value is 1 it will give list out  of index at 2
      print(students[i] + ": "+marks[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

- Python indexing begins with 0, and when you use `for i in range(n)`, it will automatically increment and you do not need to increment at the end of the loop.
- When you use `range(1,num)`, the index runs from 1 to `num - 1` only. Hence initially even though you key in 3, you get only 2 prompts.

```
    students = []
    marks = []
    num = int(input("How many students?:  "))
    for i in range(num):
         name = input("input name of student ")
         students.append(name)
         mark = input("input mark of the student")
         marks.append(mark)
    for i in range(num):
         print(students[i] + ": "+marks[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do by only input statement also

```
students = []
marks = []
num = int(input("How many students?:  "))
for i in range(num):
     name,mark = input("input name of student and marks of that student ").split(" ")
     students.append(name)
     marks.append(mark)
for i in range(num):
     print(students[i] + ": "+marks[i])
```